# Склонение: "города Химок" или "города Химки"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, ономастика

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно склонять географическое название:
"школа города Химок" или "школа города Химки"?

Comment: Пожалуйста, отметьте галочкой ответ, который вам помог.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "школа города Химок" или "школа города Химки"?

Правилен второй вариант. См. [**Письмовник на Грамоте.ру:**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/73-rubric-90)

> Географические названия в сочетании с родовым словом обычно не
>   склоняются в следующих случаях:
>
> **когда внешняя форма названия соответствует форме мн. числа:** *в городе Великие Луки, в городе Мытищи*.

Answer (score 4):

**Химки** относятся к существительным (географическим названиям), которые имеют только форму множественного числа. Например:
Карпаты, Фили, Горки, Афины, Альпы, Сокольники.

С родовым словом "город" они [Химки] не склоняются:
*Вчера **в** общеобразовательной **школе** № 31 **города Химки** прошел открытый урок балетной школы ...*
*Сегодня **в школе** № 2 **города Химки** состоялся семинар для учителей физической культуры ...*

Однако, следует помнить, что отдельно (без родового слова) Химки склоняются по общим правилам:
*На территории современных **Химок** ранее располагались сёла Куркино, Козлово, деревня Красные Горки...

В 1932 году **в Химках** был основан авиационный ремонтный завод...*
[**Химки**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B8)

**Дополнение** (к комментарию)

Географические названия, употребляемые в сочетании с родовым словом, не склоняются, если:

3. название по своей форме соответствует множественному числу: в городе Великие Луки, в городе Бережаны.
   Правильно: в Великих Луках, в Бережанах [в Химках], но: в городе Великие Луки, в городе Бережаны [в городе Химки].

[**Склонение географических названий в русском языке. Общие положения**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5)

Думаю, что Химки (в настоящий момент) относятся к существительным с формой только множественного числа (я сказала об этом в самом начале), поэтому на них и распространяется это правило.